# Reducing cyclometric complexity of a switch case

Tags: java, sonarqube, switch-statement

SonarQube says method has  too high cyclometric complexity. I'm required  to eliminate all warnings in my code,  if there's anyway to do it in such a case.

For context, the code is supposed to perform a task based on option selected

````
public void action(final char c) {
        switch (c) {
            case 'A':
                performA();
                break;
            case 'B':
                performB();
                break;
            case 'C':
                performC();
                break;
            case 'D':
                performD();
                break;
            case 'E':
                performE();
                break;
            case 'F':
                performF();
                break;
            case 'G':
               performG();
                break;
            case 'H':
                performH();
                break;
            case 'I':
                performI();
                break;
            case 'J':
                performJ();
                break;
            case 'K':
                performK();
                break;
            case 'L':
               performL();
                break;
            case 'M':
                performM();
                break;
            case 'N':
                performN();
                break;
            case 'O':
                performO();
                break;
        }
    }```
````

Comment: How about using a `Map<Character, Runnable>` instead?

Comment: When McCabe invented cyclomatic complexity, languages did not have a "switch" statement.  There's nothing wrong with your code.  Really, cyclomatic complexity is more of a concept to inspire discussion than something that needs strict adherence.

Comment: @Sweeper yeah I too thinking  same . let me see if I get any answer . Else I'll go with map

Comment: It is also possible to use reflection
@YourCustomAnnotation(trigger="n")
void performN (){ 
...
}